# Insert Hardcoded Dropdown list Values into Access Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledbconnection

I have two dropdown list and number of labels which are arranged in a date wise sequential order. The other two dropdownlist contains the year and the months.

1. How do I insert the selected value to the database?
2. How do I enter these three values- date, month, year into one column of the access database so as to represent a proper date.

I have the following C# code:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //saving date to access fields
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\dsdfg\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite21\App_Data\Cases.mdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2015" || DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2016")
    {
        str = "INSERT INTO DoctorActivity_10(DATE) values('?')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DropDownList1.Text.Trim());
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            //Suggest me what to enter here so as to store the values
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare a `string` and get all the three values from `dropdownlist` in it and insert that string into database

Comment: What datatype is the column DATE on the database?

Comment: It's of int Datatype

Comment: So you want to insert the DropDownList for year and the one for Month in that field, but what about the Day - Labels? How do you select a day from an unclickable label? Last but not least, are the months inserted in the DDL in the correct date order? (January, February etc...)

Comment: I have text box against each day. So if the user enters data into the text box and clicks the submit button- that particular date label + the value of both the dropdownlists should get inserted in the database. Yes, the  months years are in the right order

Comment: This is starting to be more complex. So your user can type in more than one textbox and you need to insert a record for each textbox that is not empty? A bit of your ASPX code could be of help to understand the relationship between the label and the textbox

Comment: I am yet to define the relationship. But it's like this, I have dates from 1st to 31st (31st or 30 or 29 or 28 th according to the month and year). Against every date(which is a label), are textboxes. If a user enters a value into those text box and presses submit button, It should get stored in the database with the date entered. I just want to understand how do I get values from a label and dropdownlist together, and store it.